# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'owner'

Tags: wagtail

here is the model

```
class CoursePage(Page):
    """docstring for Course"""
    name=RichTextField(null=False)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('it.ItCourseCategory', blank=True)
    description=StreamField([
            ('heading', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
            ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
        ])
    icon= models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(Course, self).__init__()
        self.arg = name

    content_panels=Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        StreamFieldPanel('description'),
        ImageChooserPanel('icon'),
        FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),

    ]
```

I got this

> TypeError at /admin/pages/add/it/coursepage/10/
>   **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'owner'

Answer (score 3):

You should leave out the `__init__` method.

It looks like you're trying to provide a way to pass the `name` field when creating a page, but Django already provides this capability on models such as `Page`:

```
my_course_page = CoursePage(name='<p>My course name</p>')
```

(See [the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api) for further examples.) If you choose to override the `__init__` method, you need to define it to accept all arguments and keyword arguments, and pass them on to `super`, so that this built-in behaviour doesn't break:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CoursePage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # add your own code here
```

However, in this case you don't need the `__init__` method at all.